# pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: c++

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class country
{
private:
    unsigned int residents;
    unsigned long territory;
    string hope;
    string forma_pravleniya;
    int cities;
    int constituencies;
    float GDP;
public:
    country()
    {
        residents = territory = cities = constituencies = GDP = 0;
    }
    
    country(int r, long t, int cities, int con, float GDP, string hope, string forma)
    {
        this->residents = r;
        this->territory = t;
        this->cities = cities;
        this->constituencies = con;
        this->GDP = GDP;
        this->hope = hope;
        this->forma_pravleniya = forma;
    }
    
    void out()
    {
        cout << residents <<" жителей,\t" << territory << " площадь,\t" << cities << " городов,\t" << constituencies << " округов,\t" << GDP << " ВВП,\t" << hope << "\t" << forma_pravleniya;
    }
};



int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    string fileName = "country.xml";
    ofstream countries;
    country Russia(144000000, 17125191, 1118, 8, 1.776, "Христианство", "Республика");
    country Armenia(2968000, 29743, 48, 10, 0.1336, "Христианство", "Республика");
    country USA(331900000, 9500000, 30000, 51, 25.34, "Протестантизм", "Либеральная демократия");
    countries.open(fileName);
    
    countries.write((char*)&Russia, sizeof(country));
    countries.write((char*)&USA, sizeof(country));
    countries.write((char*)&Armenia, sizeof(country));
    
    countries.close();
    
    ifstream countries_r;
    countries_r.open(fileName);
    
    country reading;
    while(countries_r.read((char*)&reading, sizeof(country)))
    {
        reading.out();
        cout << endl;
    }
    
    countries_r.close();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Нужно сделать сериализацию и диссериализацию. Хочу вывести все, что в файлике, но после того, как он выведет все, выдает ошибку:

```
LR6(22997,0x1e3386500) malloc: *** error for object 0x600000c086c0: pointer being freed was not allocated
LR6(22997,0x1e3386500) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Comment: В тексте ошибки указана причина. В чем затруднения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В С++ можно записывать или считывать как область памяти только структуры, которые отвечают конкретным требованиям. Раньше это называлось POD - Plain Old Data, позже появилось название trivial type - тривиальный тип и тип стандартной структуры (standard layout type). Полнее о тривиальных типах и типах стандартной структуры можно прочитать [например здесь](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cpp/trivial-standard-layout-and-pod-types?view=msvc-170). Кроме стандартного ограничения на тривиальность ваш тип не может иметь указателей по очевидной причине.

В вашем случае тип не тривиальный и не стандартной структуры поскольку имеет поля типа `std::string`, а следовательно его нельзя копировать через `memcpy()` и тем более записывать, а затем считывать как область памяти в/из потока. Вам нужно делать сериализацию объекта. Об этом можно например почитать [на хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/479462/)